# How to display message preview in push notification instead of title

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to display a message preview in the notification banner, currently displaying the title, and wish to display 'Text', but can't find any info on this..

Payload Format

```
["badge": 1, "alert": {
    body =     {
        Body =         {
            FromInside = 1;
            MessageId = "123456";
            Read = 0;
            Status = 0;
            Text = Hi, hows it going?;
            Timestamp = "2021-07-09T08:37:10.5020307Z";
        };
        PHONE = 07123456789;
        CODE = 123456;
        "_id" = 000000000000000000000000;
    };
    time = "7/9/2021 8:37:10 AM";
    title = "New message";
}, "sound": default]
```

userNotificationCenter

```
    func userNotificationCenter(
      _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
      didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
      withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any]
        let alert = aps!["alert"] as? [String: Any]
        let messageBody = alert!["body"] as? [String: Any]  
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {

//            let body = messageBody!["Body"] as? [String: Any] ?? nil
//            let text = body!["Text"] as? String ?? ""
            
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newMessage"), object: nil, userInfo:messageBody)
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The notification banner shows "New message" as its title, but you want it to show another text? Can you include the raw JSON you're sending the APNS endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

The `userNotificationCenter` method does not impact your remote notifications at all. If you want to change the title of the notification, you need to change it in the JSON you're sending to the APNS endpoint.

[See this table for the JSON format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification#2943363).